# ActiveMQ create persistent message in Plesk

Tags: php, activemq-classic, plesk

I am connecting to ActiveMQ from Plesk. The code used for connecting is given below

```
new Zend_Queue_Adapter_Activemq(array(
        "scheme" => "tcp",
        'driverOptions' => array(
            "host" => $ip,
            "port" => $port,
            "timeout_sec" => $delay,
            "persistent" => true),
    )
    )
```

I am sending the data using the below code

```
$adapter->send(serialize($sendData), $queue, array('persistent' => 'true'));
```

I am able to connect and send data, but the problem is the message is always showing in ActiveMQ as non-persistent. I couldn't find any sample code for this. Please help.

Comment: Activate STOMP [protocol tracing](https://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html#debugging), reproduce the problem, and then post the logs.

Comment: Also, please include your ActiveMQ configuration.